# Finding escaped groups in a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find escaped commands in a regex pattern.

The problem I'm meeting is that I can't take care of escaped backslashes before one escaping backslash. The following code, which looks for regex groups `\g<...>` in a pattern to be compiled, doesn't find the group named `not_escaped` : the raw string `\\\\\g` is the seen as a sequence of escaped backslashes followed by an unescaped group `\g` from the regex point of view.

```
import re

p = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)\\g<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*)>")

for m in p.finditer(
    r"</\g<name_1>\g<name_2>\\\\\g<not_escaped>\\g<escaped>>>"
):
    print(m.group(1))
```

This code gives the names `name_1` and `name_2`, but if the text is compiled by `re`, the groups normally used, if I'm not wrong, will be the groups `name_1`, `name_2` and `not_escaped`.

Comment: What's a command, and what's an escaped command?

Comment: "the raw string `\\\\\g` is the litteral string `\\\g` which is a escaped backslash followed by a unescaped `\g`" - no it's not. It's 5 literal backslashes and a g.

Comment: Even in a string that is one regex to be compiled ?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't *match* 5 literal backslashes and a g if you try to use it as a regex, but that's what it is.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks but the problem stays... I've updated my question.

Comment: What is this part for? `(?<!\\)` Seems like this is the problem.

Comment: @tobias_k Initially, I've used that so as to find escaped groups `\g` like the last one in my example. This looks for something that must not be behind another thing.

Comment: Seems like the number of `\\` before the `g` has to be an odd number?

Comment: Please provide some more examples which input you want to match and which you do _not_ want to match.  I've got an idea what you mean but the only two examples you've rpvided this far don't seem to be sufficient.

Comment: @Alfe Another update has been done. Hoping that the question has been clarified...

Comment: Are you trying to write [`expand`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.expand)?

Comment: No. Indeed, I want to change names of os some `\g` groups in a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match odd numbers of backslashes just use this pattern:

```
r'(?<!\)(\\\\)*\\g...'
```

But I think in your case you will have to search for backslash counts dividable by four (and then one additional backslash), so you should use this:

```
p = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)(\\\\\\\\)*\\g<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*)>")
for m in p.finditer(
    r"</\g<name_1>\g<name_2>\\\\\g<not_escaped>\\\g<escaped>>>"):
  print(m.group(2))
```

It finds the three you wanted and not the fourth you didn't want.

Comment: Yes, I want to escape an odd number of backslashes. I've tried your first pattern which does the job. Thanks ! I was not looking in the good direction.